# Assembly size of instructions from objdump

Tags: assembly, x86

using objdump -d , i get

```
 80483b7:   e9 73 7c fb f7          jmp    2f <_init-0x8048265>
 80483bc:   5e                      pop    %esi
 80483bd:   89 76 08                mov    %esi,0x8(%esi)
```

does this mean that for example the size of jmp instruction is 5 bytes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does this mean that for example the size of jmp instruction is 5 bytes

Yes, however, you can get jumps of other sizes, so always check first with objdump and consult the intel instruction manuals.

Comment: Thanks, one more question with jmp I intend to advance instruction pointer by 0x2f but you can see <_init-0x8048265> which is not 2f bytes below the jmp
maybe I'll use labels or get the address from eip and add the offset

Comment: @netassemble: `JMP 2F` means jump to 0x2F, not jump by 0x2F, to jump by 0x2F you can use the encoding `0xEB 0x2F` (relative jump of 0x2F). if you are doing this in an assembler, labels are the best way to do it.